# Исходящие ссылки (разные) с сайта редиректить на 1 ссылку

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть сайт.
У него есть исходящие ссылки.
Они редиректятся таким образом

```
<input type="button" value="Перейти" onclick="window.open('http://сайт-на-который-происходит-редирект.tld/redir1.html');" class="button" />
```

...

```
redir2.html
redir3.html
```

Хотелось бы оперативно перенаправить все исходящие ссылки на другой 1 конкретный адрес сайта, например на гугл.

Чтобы любой клик по кнопкам с адресами

```
http://сайт-на-который-происходит-редирект.tld/redir1.html
      redir2.html
    redir3.html
```

Редиректил например на гугл

(без исправления исходящих ссылок в коде) чтобы когда-то оперативно все вернуть как было.

Каким методом это можно сделать, подскажите?

htaccess?
php?

Comment: а это `site.tld` - ваш сайт ?

Comment: Нет, `site.tld` это внешний сайт

Comment: Скажите, а зачем вы перенаправляете ссылки на чей-то чужой сайт? Они там точно рады вашим перенаправлениям?

Comment: Ну как вариант анонс статей, и кнопка "ПОДРОБНЕЕ", а сами статьи на другом сайте

Comment: А когда тот сайт перестал на время работать, то бог с ними со статьями, перенаправить хоть куда, лишь бы лишь бы.... создать видимость работы кнопок "ПОДРОБНЕЕ"

Comment: Вредительство какое-то, п.м.с.м.

Answer (score 1):

C JQuery можно так

```
$(function(){
    var redirectToAdvertising = function() { 
        location.href = "http://google.com/";
        return false;
    }
    //В нужный момент вешаем событие на клик по всем ссылкам на странице
    $("a").on("click", redirectToAdvertising);
    //В другой нужный момент - снимаем событие
    $("a").off("click", redirectToAdvertising);
});
```

На нативном JS лень писать, но там не сильно сложнее